# Antenna factor vs receiver noise

Tags: rf, antenna, emc

I am trying to make sense of a radiated emission measurement according to CISPR25. According to that standard, there is a maximum average emission of 10 dBµV/m at 1575 MHz (for GPS L1). I have  doubts if the equipment used is actually capable of measuring this properly due to the inherent noise of the test receiver.

Here is what I calculated, at 1575 MHz:

- the receiver noise at is 1 dBµV
- the antenna factor is 24 dB/m
- the antenna gain is 7 dBi

Therefore the electric field strength representing the receiver noise is 1 dBµv + 24 dB/m - 7 dBi = 19 dBµV/m. Thus there is more noise than the emission level (10 dBµV/m) to be measured, and I conclude that it is not possible to use this equipment for this kind of measurement.

Is my thinking correct?

Some more details on bandwidth: The bandwidth for the receiver can be set as 1 Hz, 10 Hz, 100 Hz, 200 Hz, 1 kHz, 9 kHz, 10 kHz, 100 kHz, 120 kHz, 1 MHz, 10 MHz. The noise figures for 1575 MHz is given only for an BW of 1 MHz at the 1 dBµV reported above. The measurement according to CISPR25 however demands a bandwidth of 9 kHz. Does that reduced bandwidth also lead in a predictable wayto a reduced noise figure?

Comment: Have you assumed a receiver BW of around 100 kHz? What temperature did you assume?

Comment: The noise spec is for 1 MHz RBW, and between 5C and 40C. However, CISPR25  demands a RBW of 9 kHz, but there is no spec for that in the test receiver documentation.

Comment: The test receiver will be like a spectrum analyser and it will have a very tight BW.